# How to set a content-type for a specific file with Rack?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, rack, file-type, html-components

I want to have Rack serve a specific file with a specific content type. It's a .htc file and it needs to be served as text/x-component so that IE will recognize it. In apache I would just do

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

How can I achieve this with Rack? Currently the file is served by Rack::Static, but I didn't find an option to set the content type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can update your `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` like this:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Add new mime types for use in respond_to blocks:
# Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
# Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :iphone

Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.merge!({
  ".ogg"     => "application/ogg",
  ".ogx"     => "application/ogg",
  ".ogv"     => "video/ogg",
  ".oga"     => "audio/ogg",
  ".mp4"     => "video/mp4",
  ".m4v"     => "video/mp4",
  ".mp3"     => "audio/mpeg",
  ".m4a"     => "audio/mpeg",
  ".htc"     => "text/x-component"
})
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I had no mime_types.rb, so I put it directly into the config.ru file.

Comment: sorry, sure you didn't have one, it's from rails, but since rails is a rack up, it works.

Comment: Normally my Rack projects don't have a config/initializers directory, only my rails projects have...

Answer (score 0):

Or just to reply to the question, add this in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
Mime::Type.register "text/x-component", :htc
```